# Selecting right button iMacros

Tags: imacros

So, I recorded this from iMacro, and when i replay it, it follows just the first user, how do i get the script to follow the 2nd one?

```
EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR="#followButton" BUTTON=0
EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR="#followButton" BUTTON=0
EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR="#followButton" BUTTON=0
EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR="#followButton" BUTTON=0
EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR="#followButton" BUTTON=0
```

It follows only the first one, and that's all

Answer (score 0):

Change your recording option to this:

[image]